# Problemas con URLs en Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

La cuestión es esta, resulta que cuando utilizo el helper de codeigniter: "form", la url que genera para la propiedad action presenta algo extraño al principio, esto [::1]. Qué significa aquello? Qué debo configurar para que muestre correctamente la ip, en mi caso 127.0.0.1

```
 <?php echo form_open('cliente/get'); ?>
            <h3>Buscar</h3>
            <input type="text"  id="ci-busq" />
            <button type="button" onclick="buscarCliente(event)"> Ok</button>
    </form>
```

Viendo en la consola del navegador, compruebo que la url generada es así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tu archivo `config.php` tienes definida tu base url?

$config['base_url'] = "localhost/tusitioweb"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto sucede porque tu `base_url` está vacía. Lo único que necesitas hacer es ir a el archivo `config.php` que se encuentra en el directorio: `application/config/config.php`.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/proyecto';
```

El texto `[::1]` es equivalente a `localhost`.

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
::1          localhost
```

Más información en: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)

Referencia de respuesta: [Codeigniter echoing [::1] instead of localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35876229/7011427)